# view source code is not showing up on view source code when I use in within update panel

Tags: asp.net, listview, updatepanel

I am implementing an update panel for my web page ASP.net 4.0 C#. The update panel has a dropdown and a listview. When I run my site , I am able to see listview details (images and info) in my browser but when I do view source for my page , listview and its contents  tag is missing. Please can you let me know why listview details are not appearing when I do a "view source"?

Answer (score 1):

The View Source option shows you exactly that - the original source code for the page.

If you want to see any elements what were added dynamically to the page, you have to view the current DOM structure. You can do that using tools like the IE Developer tools, the Firefox Inspector, or the Firefox plugin Firebug.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have a jquery script that parses through the DOM elements. Will that be able to see the dynamically added elements?

Comment: Firebug plugin in Forefox browser should help, yes.

Comment: @vaishu: Yes, that will see the current elements.